# carthageでRealmをインストールは出来てもコンパイルが出来ません

Tags: swift, xcode, realm, swift2, xcode7

以下のサイトを参考に、carthageを使ってRealmをインストールするところまでは行きました。

https://realm.io/jp/docs/swift/latest/

しかし、いざXcodeでコンパイルしようとしてもエラーで弾かれてしまいます。

```
Failed to read file or folder at　/Users/[私の名前]/Desktop/Xcode/[project名]/myfile
Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1
```

基本的にCarthageで必要な手続きである

- embeded Binariesへの登録（realm realmSwiftの両方）
- RunScriptで/usr/local/bin/carthage copy-frameworksの記述と、inputfilesへのパス記述
  （無論何度も確認しましたが、間違いはありませんでした）

を完了しているはずなのですが...

何か心当たりがあるかたはいらっしゃらないでしょうか？
よろしくお願いいたします

Comment: ちなみにエラー時に出るパスなのですが、project名の後にmyfileとありますが、実際にはそんな名前ではありません。
何か関係はあるのでしょうか？

Comment: どこかにプロジェクトをアップロードして見せてもらうことはできますか？公開できないものならhelp@realm.ioに送ってくれませんか？

Comment: kashikawa katsumiさん
ご返答ありがとうございます
アップロードの方法がわからなかったので、help@realm.ioに送りました。
よろしくお願いいたします

Comment: ありがとうございます。結論から言いますと、プロジェクトの設定には何の問題もありませんでした。単にビルドするだけでシミュレータ、デバイス両方とも動作しました。おそらく古い情報が残って問題が起こってるだけだと思いますので、プロジェクトのクリーン、`~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData`の削除などを試してみてください。削除の方法がわからない場合は、こちら https://ez-net.jp/article/C9/qUKZiJ9B/vI-nxInyf79k/ などを参考にしてください。

Comment: kashikawa katsumiさん
ありがとうございます！
cleanをかけたら出来ました！
これからは古い情報を疑うようにしてみます........

Answer (score 1):

恐らく古い情報が残って問題を起こしている可能性があるので、「プロジェクトのクリーン」を試してみてください。

---

*この投稿は [@kishikawa katsumi さんのコメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/24657/carthage%e3%81%a7realm%e3%82%92%e3%82%a4%e3%83%b3%e3%82%b9%e3%83%88%e3%83%bc%e3%83%ab%e3%81%af%e5%87%ba%e6%9d%a5%e3%81%a6%e3%82%82%e3%82%b3%e3%83%b3%e3%83%91%e3%82%a4%e3%83%ab%e3%81%8c%e5%87%ba%e6%9d%a5%e3%81%be%e3%81%9b%e3%82%93#comment23560_24657) の内容を元に コミュニティwiki として投稿しました。*